# Eight queens in C++

Tags: c++, chess

The idea behind this problem is to represent a configuration of 8 queens with a one-dimensional array. So a[0] represents the first row, a[1] the second row etc. and `a[row]=column` position, where column position represents the "row position" of the queen.

Is there anything I can improve?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a[7];
    int m, b, i=0, x, y, k=0, c,u;

    for(u=0; u<8; u++){
        cin>>a[u];
    }

    for(m=0; m<7; m++){

        for(b=m+1; b<=7; b++){

            if(a[m]==a[b]) i++;
        }

    }   
    for(x=0; x<7; x++){
        c=0;
        for(y=x+1; y<=7; y++){
            c++;
            if(abs(a[x]-a[y])==c) k++;

        }
    }

    if(i==0 && k==0) cout<<"valid";
    else cout<<"invalid";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

- `using namespace std` [is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). In this case it is unjustified as well.
- `int a[7]` only has room for 7 elements. You put 8 there. This is plain UB.
- Avoid magic numbers. Define a `const int board_size = 8`. `board_size` and `board_size - 1` are understood much better than a random mix of `7` and `8`.
- An idiomatic counting `for` loop terminating condition is expressed with `<`, not `<=`:

  ```
      for (....; b < board_size; ....)
  ```
- Avoid single letter variables. Variable name usually conveys some meaning. In this case, board coordinates are traditionally called `rank` and `file`.
- Declare variables as close the use as possible (e.g. `for (int x = 0; ...)`).
- Terminate early. Instead of `i++` you may immediately say `std::cout << "invalid"; return 0;` (same with `k`), thus eliminating unneeded variables.